# How do I disable iCloud for just one app?

Tags: ipad, icloud

I want to restart one of my games on my iPad, so I uninstalled it, but when i go to reinstall it and start over, it just shows me the cloud option to continue from where I left off. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your running iOS 8.1, on your iPad, go to Settings -> iCloud -> Storage -> Manage Storage. Once your there under Documents & Data you should see your game. Just tap on the game you want to delete (reset) and click Edit, the the Delete All button will appear. Tap on that, and your game should be reset (you may have to Quit and/or delete the app to make the changes take place).